# Why do the dominant color in (R,G,B) format from a snipped image varies from the same image using image slicing from opencv or skimage library?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, rgb

I have a high-resolution image (2316x2148) and I just cropped them manually using the snipping tool in windows [as fig 1] and checked the dominant color (RGB code - 146,55,61) using "colorthief library". When the same image is read using OpenCV or skimage and the same old cropped region is sliced and stored as a jpg image as shown in fig 2, the corresponding RGB code from colorthief is - 130,57,60.

I want to know why this is occurring and how to get 146,55,61 by using python slicing.

[image: fig 1 manually snipped image]             [image: fig 2 sliced image]

Comment: JPEG compression modifies the colors slightly.

Comment: You probably lost an attached colour profile when opening with OpenCV.

Comment: The two images have different colours, so it is ok that you get different dominant colour. So now you should check why the two images have different colours. Maybe you are using a different colour space (or a limited range vs. full range)?

Comment: @KlausD. Counting this issue I changed the original image into png format and tried but still there was no change in the results.

Comment: @MarkSetchell. I changed from opencv to skimage to read and write images. Also, in opencv I read the image with cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED thinking that I left any color space. But still there was no improvement in the results.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi. Both the crops are from the same image. The only difference was I used Microsoft photos viewer to open the image and snipping tool to crop as shown in fig 1. Whereas I used opencv to open the image in the second case and used python slicing to crop the image and saved it using cv2.imwrite. But finally the color appears different even in the visual inspection!

Comment: On my screen, I see different colours on the two images, and quite noticeable. It doesn't matter if the origin is the same image, but it matter how the toops manage the crop, and if they change colour spaces. Remember that images usually do not have RGB data (but it is in usually in sRGB colour space): JPEG is by default YCC.

Comment: Thankyou it was a nice hint about sRGB from which I got to know about the ICC profile. After some more research about this I got to know that Opencv and other libraries do not include the ICC profile when I read or write images. So, only there is change in the RGB for the above image. I found that only PIL library has a method to attach the ICC profile. But I am trying to do the same using opencv.